# Can a Entity Framework Trackable collection be bound to an ASP.Net Gridview?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, poco, self-tracking-entities

I've got a GridView on a ASP.Net page. I would like to set the DataSource of the Gridview to a trackable collection of Entity Framework objects. I though the code should look like this:

```
        this.gvMyGridView.DataSource = entity.MyDetailedItems;
        this.gvMyGridView.DataBind();
```

But this doesn't display any data.

I am using self tracking entities and the MyDetailedItems is a navigation property to rows from another table.

Answer (score 1):

EF 4 with [self tracking entities does not support lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362922/how-do-i-correctly-use-ef4-nagivation-properties/5363155#5363155) so you must explicitly load navigation properties if you want to use them. Use either:

```
// loading entity with related entities
var entity = context.Entities.Include("MyDetailedItems").Single(...);
```

or

```
// loading related entities for already loaded entity
context.LoadProperty(entity, "MyDetailedItems");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.  If you are not using the lazy loading (LazyLoadingEnabled to true), then these relationships do not automatically load, and you have to do:

```
if (entity.MyDetailedItems.IsLoaded == false)
    entity.MyDetailedItems.Load();
```

Before binding, otherwise, if using EF 4 turn on lazy loading enabled, and this no longer becomes a problem.

HTH.